# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseVisionImage' error in Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-machine-learning

I am currently making a basic google lens app and I'm struggling with this error. Is there a way to fix this?

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-mode:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

The coding(image link is under the coding):

```
private void getResults(){
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);
    FirebaseVisionImageLabeler labeler = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceImageLabeler();

    labeler.processImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<>());
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvZhi.png

I would be really appreciated for your advice and help, thank you.

Comment: the coding isnt finished yet, i cant find the visionimage library

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper imports in your file? The `FirebaseVisionImage` object exists at `com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage` as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImage).

Answer (score 0):

If you had this error like i did, Go to Tools, select Firebase, go to Firebase ML click "Use Firebase ML to recognize and labels images". Connect to Firebase and Add Firebase ML to your app. You can also choose the second option "text in images" if you want to